# C File Homework

Tags: c

This is my homework: http://oi40.tinypic.com/o9l3wn.jpg

**Synopsis**

A sequential access file `"inf.txt"` has some student records which contains the following for each student:

1. ID NUMBER
2. FIRST NAME
3. LAST NAME
4. HOMEWORK
5. MIDTERM,
6. FINAL

Write a C main function to read file `"inf.txt"` records to compute the final numeric grade of each student first, then convert it into the letter grade by using the grading system below and finally write each student's record into a sequential access file `"outf.txt"`.
Records of `"outf.txt"` file will contain the following for each student:

1. ID NUMBER
2. FIRST NAME
3. LAST NAME
4. NUMERIC GRADE
5. LETTER GRADE

The program will use a `struct` variable when reading and writing file records (i.e a C structure will be declared and defined to represent the file record).

Grading system:

> NUMERIC: HOMEWORK 15% , MIDTERM 35%,   FINAL  50%
>   LETTER: 0-40 FF, 41-45 DD, 46-52 DC, 53-60 CC, 61-69 CB, 70-79 BB, 80-89 BA, 90++  AA.

To test the program you should create (using any editor) an input text file (`inf.txt`) with at least 10 records. A typical record of the input file may look like the one as shown below:

```
ID   FIRST NAME   LAST NAME   HOMEWORK   MIDTERM   FINAL
xx   xxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx      75        55       80
```

This is what I have.  Can you please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct info
{   
    int ID, HWORK, MIDTERM, FINAL, NUMGRADE;
    char NAME[20], LASTNAME[20];
} rec;

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr1, *fptr2;
    int NUMGRADE;
    char LETGRADE[3] = "";

    fptr1 = fopen("inf.txt.", "r");
    fptr2 = fopen("outf.txt.", "w");

    while(!feof(fptr1))
    {
        fscanf (fptr1, "%d %s %s %d %d %d", &rec.ID, rec.NAME, rec.LASTNAME, &rec.HWORK, &rec.MIDTERM, &rec.FINAL);

        NUMGRADE = rec.HWORK * 0, 15 + rec.MIDTERM * 0, 35 + rec.FINAL * 0, 5;

        if(NUMGRADE >= 0 && NUMGRADE <= 40) LETGRADE[3] = "FF";
        else if (NUMGRADE >= 41 && NUMGRADE <= 45) LETGRADE[3] = "DD";
        else if (NUMGRADE >= 46 && NUMGRADE <= 52) LETGRADE[3] = "DC";
        else if (NUMGRADE >= 53 && NUMGRADE <= 60) LETGRADE[3] = "CC";
        else if (NUMGRADE >= 61 && NUMGRADE <= 69) LETGRADE[3] = "CB";
        else if (NUMGRADE >= 70 && NUMGRADE <= 79) LETGRADE[3] = "BB";
        else if (NUMGRADE >= 80 && NUMGRADE <= 89) LETGRADE[3] = "BA";
        else if (NUMGRADE >= 90) LETGRADE[3] = "AA";        

        fprintf (fptr2, "%d %s %s %d %s", &rec.ID, rec.NAME, rec.LASTNAME, &NUMGRADE, LETGRADE);        
    }

    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a problem description that is useful. In what **specific way** does it not work? Which part of the code? You need to [edit] your question to be more specific about the problem, and ask an actual question we can answer. "Can you help me" isn't a specific programming question, I'm afraid.

Comment: Your entire problem description is just "it didn't work". That's totally unhelpful. Did it compile? Did it link? Did it run? What did it do? What did you expect?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "It did not work" is not a sufficient explanation of your problem.  We are not mind readers, so please elaborate.

Comment: Exactly what the above users posted. Specifically **what** doesn't work?

Comment: Well, I had some little hope when I saw actual code, but then.. 'It didn't work :/Can you help me, please'.  Please tell us what did not work, and any info. you have found during your own debugging.

Comment: `LETGRADE[3]="DD"` can't in C. use `strcpy`.

Comment: I'm not good at this topic but I think the parts with the problem are if-else if part.

Comment: 'while (!feof(fptr1))' - feof() only returns a valid result AFTER a read operation.

Comment: There's no way this compiles...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is add error checking to *every* function you call. Check the documentation for `fopen`. How do you tell if the call failed? How do you accurately report the error if it did? Most likely, once you do these things, the problem will become obvious.

It's okay in my book to write code without error checking first. This is because adding error checking can distract you while you're trying to get the functional stuff done. But you *must* go back and add the error checking before you can consider the code complete. And, obviously, you need it to figure out why the code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but I think you might wanna remove some of the & from this line:

fprintf (fptr2, "%d %s %s %d %s",&rec.ID,rec.NAME,rec.LASTNAME,&NUMGRADE,LETGRADE);

Answer (score 0):

In the fprintf statement you don't need to take the address of rec.ID or NUMGRADE

```
fprintf (fptr2, "%d %s %s %d %s",rec.ID,rec.NAME,rec.LASTNAME,NUMGRADE,LETGRADE);
                                 ^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If when you say that it didn't work you mean that it didn't compile is because there are much error in your code. For example is wrong the following line of code:

```
LETGRADE[3]="DD"
```

The variable `LETGRADE` is an array of `char` and it means that every element of the array is a `char` so you cannot assign a string to a char. Supposing your `LETGRADE` array must store two character you don't need that it has three size (two is enough). Then you can assign for example the string `AA` with the following code:

```
char LETGRADE[2];
/* ... */
LETGRADE[0] = 'A';
LETGARDE[1] = 'A';
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct info {

int ID,HWORK,MIDTERM,FINAL,NUMGRADE;
char NAME[20], LASTNAME[20];

} rec;

int main() {

FILE *fptr1,*fptr2;
int NUMGRADE;
char* LETGRADE="";

fptr1=fopen("inf.txt","r");
fptr2=fopen("outf.txt","w");
rec* reg = malloc(sizeof(rec));

while (EOF != fscanf(fptr1, "%d %s %s %d %d %d",&reg->ID,reg->NAME,reg->LASTNAME,&reg->HWORK,&reg->MIDTERM,&reg->FINAL)){
    NUMGRADE=reg->HWORK*0.15+reg->MIDTERM*0.35+reg->FINAL*0.5;
    if (NUMGRADE>=0 && NUMGRADE<=40) LETGRADE="FF";
    else if (NUMGRADE>=41 && NUMGRADE<=45) LETGRADE="DD";
    else if (NUMGRADE>=46 && NUMGRADE<=52) LETGRADE="DC";
    else if (NUMGRADE>=53 && NUMGRADE<=60) LETGRADE="CC";
    else if (NUMGRADE>=61 && NUMGRADE<=69) LETGRADE="CB";
    else if (NUMGRADE>=70 && NUMGRADE<=79) LETGRADE="BB";
    else if (NUMGRADE>=80 && NUMGRADE<=89) LETGRADE="BA";
    else if (NUMGRADE>=90) LETGRADE="AA";
    fprintf (fptr2, "%d %s %s %d %s\n",reg->ID,reg->NAME,reg->LASTNAME,NUMGRADE,LETGRADE);
}


fclose(fptr1);
fclose(fptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's better not assign a `string` to a `char` pointer. I prefer use `strncpy` for that.

Comment: @Mpac i am not a expert in c but i do not see any problems in asign a string literal to a pointer... you can´t do this with an array... but with pointers its ok... further reference: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html